# Running vaadin 7 application in IE 6 browser

Tags: internet-explorer-6, vaadin7, google-chrome-frame

We are running a web-application that is based on Vaadin 7. This application runs fine in IE 7 and higher but it doesn't work in IE 6.

We tried various approaches and followed few approaches mentioned in Vaadin document but couldn't make it work.

Then we found this plugin "Google Chrome Frame". On using this we are able to see first login screen but with a session expired message.

Can any one having experience with Vaadin help us out here in order to make Vaadin 7 application run in IE6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot make your Vaadin 7 application to work with IE6 because Vaadin 7 doesn't support IE6.